# Aggregate data for a monthly group in multiple temp tables

Tags: sum, aggregate

I have multiple temp tables, and I am taking a date from each temp table and getting a monthly count. At the end, I want to create one large table to give a total count by month for each category. I got the math working, but I can't figure out how to list one month and give all the data for that month.

SQL Code:

```
/*
Get Orders put in by staff
*/
if object_id('tempdb..#suborder') is not null drop table #suborder 
select a.CustSID, a.enteredDateTime, a.EnteredByEmpSID

into #suborder
from Truck.Order a
where a.enteredDateTime >= '20180801'
and a.enteredDateTime <= '20180829'

if object_id('tempdb..#order') is not null drop table #order 
select month(a.enteredDateTime) as CM,
count (a.CustSID) as 'Order Count'

into #order
from #suborder a
join emp.employee b on b.EmpSID = a.EnteredbyEmpSID 

where  b.EmpName = @name
group by month(a.enteredDateTime)
order by month(a.enteredDateTime)

/*
Get # of Notes entered by a Employee
*/

if object_id('tempdb..#subnote') is not null drop table #subnote 
select a.custSID, a.EnteredByEmpSID, a.EntryDateTime 

into #subnote
from doc.storage a
where a.EntryDateTime >= '20180801' 
and a.EntryDateTime <= '20180930'
and a.signedbyStaffSID is not null 

if object_id('tempdb..#note') is not null drop table #note
select month(a.EntryDateTime) as CM,
count (a.custSID) as 'Note Count'

into #note
from #subnote a
join emp.employee b on b.EmpSID = a.EnteredbyEmpSID 
where b.EmpName = @name 
group by month(a.EntryDateTime)
order by month(a.EntryDateTime)

/*
Join all the counts together and sum total workload
*/

 SELECT o.CM,
   n.CM,
   o.[Order Count] + n.[Note Count] [Total Workload]
   FROM #order o
        cross join #note n
```

My end result, I would like:

```
CM        Order Count        Note Count       Total Workload
8          15                 30               45
9          17                 25               42
```

Currently I am getting:

```
CM        CM         Order Count        Note Count        Total Workload
8         8            15                 30                45
9         9            17                 25                42
```

Comment: Don't you think only removing 1 CM from select clause will solve your problem. Coz I am not able to see any differences other than an extra col CM.

Comment: By removing all the CM's but one, it gave 32 lines with the same data.  The extra CMs are the other CMs in the temp tables from the date months for notes and orders.

Comment: I was indicating that remove 1 CM only from select clause. Removing or adding any columns from select clause can never manipulate your no of records.